# newbie Raising an Exception

Tags: python, exception

This is my first attempt at coding anything other than a Fanuc CNC control. I dont know why but this code returns both exceptions and if I remove the raise Exception from the else: it doesnt return either exception. What am I missing?

```
cut_type=[input("Enter cut type Straight(S) or Arc(A)" )]# Add Taper later

try:
    if 'S' in cut_type:
        valid_type=['Y']
    elif 's' in cut_type:
        valid_type=['Y']
    elif 'A' in cut_type:
        valid_type=['Y']
    elif 'a' in cut_type:
        valid_type=['Y']
    else:
        valid_type=['N']
        raise Exception('Cut Type not Valid')
except:
    print('NOT VALID TYPE')
    raise Exception('Cut Type not Valid')
print(valid_type)
```

If I run the above code I get the following

```
Enter cut type Straight(S) or Arc(A)q
NOT VALID TYPE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Chip Break testing.py", line 21, in <module>
    raise Exception('Cut Type not Valid')
Exception: Cut Type not Valid

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Chip Break testing.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise Exception('Cut Type not Valid')
Exception: Cut Type not Valid
```

And if I run it with the raise Exception removed from either of the positions I don't get any exception. I know I'm missing something simple but I cannot see it.

Comment: In the ```else``` part, ```Exception``` is raised ```raise Exception('Cut Type not Valid')```, which is caught by  the **bare ```except:```** where another exception is raised

Comment: What's your intended behavior? That sounds like the correct behavior of that program to me. What do you want it to do?

Comment: Yes that would be the reason for both exceptions. If you remove the else block you would have an error on `print(valid_type)` as it was never assigned. What is the input you're using and what is your expected output?

Comment: If the type is invalid, why are you adding anything to `valid_type`?

Comment: Are you *intending* to catch the error you yourself raise in the `else` block inside `try`? It's hard to understand what you are trying to do here

Comment: like i said, total newbie, I am trying to rasie an exception if the 'cut_type' does not match what is allowed for calculations later. Now that I am thinking more about it I think it would be easier to check if 'cut_type' is in a list vs what I have here.

Comment: @TonyMixer so, general advice, always try to raise/catch **as specific an error as possible*, and make your `try` block *as localized as possible*. But OK, just still trying to understand you, but what is the `try-` block *for*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, after you questioned the `try` block I relooked at it and I ended up removing it and the `except` as well as my `valid_type` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did after suggestions and relooking at my code to make it work.

```
cut_type=[input("Enter cut type Straight(S) or Arc(A)" )]# Add Taper later
 
if 'S' in cut_type:
    pass    
elif 's' in cut_type:
    pass    
elif 'A' in cut_type:
    pass    
elif 'a' in cut_type:
    pass    
else:
    raise Exception('Cut Type not Valid')
```

Thank you everyone. I am hoping to learn more and switch careers.